# Mint ID Requested

Tags: identification, perennials

[image: This mint came with the house. 30 years ago. It is beautiful and about eight feet tall. I was wondering if anyone knows what it is. Definitely mint. Thanks in advance.]

This mint came with the house.  30 years ago.  It is beautiful and about eight feet tall.  I was wondering if anyone knows what it is.  Definitely mint.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a beautiful specimen of [*Lantana camara*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana_camara), a member of the Verbenaceae family. It’s not a mint, but many Verbenaceae are scented and some are used as herbs, for example lemon verbena and vervain.

Lantana camara is also used in traditional herbalist medicine, but its toxicity means you should probably be careful and not use it on your own.

Where conditions are favorable, it can be an invasive plant, out-competing others. Its relative robustness and the attractive color-changing flowers brought it into the focus of breeders, so now many cultivars are available with a wide range of colors. That its blooms attract butterflies adds to its charms as decorative plants.

Comment: So no mint tea.  I'm glad I asked.  I don't think of it as a herb, but a flowering tree like my magnolia.  When in full bloom like today it is truly gorgeous.  Thanks for the answer.